# Plot points linked with edges using gnuplot

Tags: vector, gnuplot

I have a file of points (x, y) that I plot using gnuplot. If I have another file that shows which point is linked with which other point by an edge (e.g. (3.8, 6) linked to (4,7)), is it possible to visualise/plot this edges between points ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

depending on how your data is organized, you may want to look into plotting `with vectors`.
For example, if your datafile looks like:

```
#x1 y1 x2 y2
 1  1  3   3
```

You can plot this using:

```
set style arrow 1 nohead
plot "my_arrows.dat" using 1:2:($3-$1):($4-$2) with vectors arrowstyle 1
```

**EDIT**

Assuming all the points in your datafile are repeated, you can do the following:

```
set style arrow 1 nohead
plot "my_arrows.dat" using 1:2:($3-$1):($4-$2) with vectors arrowstyle 1,\
     "my_arrows.dat" using 1:2 w points
```

If they're not repeated, you can do:

```
set style arrow 1 nohead
plot "my_arrows.dat" using 1:2:($3-$1):($4-$2) with vectors arrowstyle 1,\
     "my_arrows.dat" using 1:2 w points ls 1 lc rgb "red" pt 1,\
     "my_arrows.dat" using 3:4 w points ls 1 lc rgb "red" pt 1
```

Note that you can play around with the linestyles (`linecolor` or `lc`, `pointtype` or `pt`, `linewidth` or `lw` etc. to make the points appear the same.)

Comment: That's awesome, so I just need to rearrange my arrows file to follow this format (x1 y1 x2 y2). The only problem is just that the points are not visible when linked with the arrow. What should I add to your command so that the points will be visible ?

Comment: See my updated post.  I hope I understand your question properly.

Comment: using 4 points in my_arrows.dat "2 6 4 9" and "4 7 3 5", I get the following (I tried your last command) which seems incorrect: http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/639362lllolz.png

Comment: So by the way, the command "plot "my_arrows.dat" using 1:2:($3-$1):($4-$1) with vectors arrowstyle 1" seems incorrect since it does not link point (2 6) with point (4 9), and the point (4 7) with (3 5)

Comment: Sorry, it should be `($4-$2)`, not `($4-$1)`.  Typing error on my part which persisted since I was just copy/pasting.  ;).  I've updated my answer.  It should be correct now.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. By the way, I have a C++ program that manipulate a graph (update (add/delete) edges and vertices). Do you know if it is possible to plot the manipulated graph using gnuplot (like we did here) from my C++ program and update the plot each time the graph is updated ? A sort of animation ...

Comment: In order to do something like that, you'll probably need to open gnuplot from your C++ program using `popen` and then resend the plot commands every time you update the file.

Comment: I'm note sure I can use the function popen, I'm on windows

Answer (score 2):

You might not be able to read the line positions in without using a separate utility to generate your plotscript, but the command to draw a line from point to point is

```
set arrow [X] from first x1,y1 to first x2,y2 nohead
```

where X is an optional tag number for the arrow, and (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) are points in the graph's coordinate system.

Comment: first, is it possible to have an undirected arrow ? second, I have a file which says for each point with which other point it is associated. Should I thus generate a corresponding file a which will containing a command "set arrow .." for each association (this is what you called "plotscript") ?

Comment: Ok, for the first question, I see that I can add "nohead" at the end to have an undirected arrow. Now to generate the script that should link each point to some others, which kind of script should I generate (I'll generate it using python), is it just a succession of commands "set arrow from Xi,Yi to first Xj,Yj nohead" ?

Comment: You're right, I forgot to add the `nohead` option originally.  A plotscript is just a file which contains commands you would otherwise type in gnuplot.  You can use it by typing `gnuplot plotscript.plt` at the command line (the file extension does not matter), or you can type `load plotscript.plt` from within gnuplot.  You're also right about the file you want to generate containing commands--just a bunch of `set arrow...` commands.